# How do you deadhead a snapdragon?

Tags: flowers, deadheading

I'm used to deadheading roses and mums and other "normal" flower shapes. We bought some gorgeous maroon snapdragons for way too much and I'd like to deadhead them to encourage more blooms. Should I cut the whole stalk off or pinch the flowers individually as they wither? If I cut the stalk, is there something to look for to indicate the right place to cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just looking for something similar the other day and found this article that explains how to deadhead snapdragons. I found this:

*Look for flower stalks that are already mostly bare, as these are starting to produce seeds. Look closely as you may mistake them for bare stems. Cut these stalks off at the base and dispose of them.*

My source is [here](https://www.gardenguides.com/95251-deadhead-snapdragons.html). Hope it helps! Let me know how it turns out - I'm a ways away from needing to do this, but am intrigued. :-)

Comment: I snipped them down a few days ago. I went about 3/4 the way down the stalk and snipped them just above where I found good new growth on the stalk. I will keep an eye on them and let you know.

Comment: Sure enough, there is new growth coming off where I snipped and now that growth has flower buds on it.